# Pass different files as parameters

Tags: circos

I have a few queries with regards to Circos plots.

1. I want to include a legend within the plot to indicate what does the different circles within the plot represent.
2. I want to rename the plot sub-routines in a way that when I run circos I can use param properties to pass the files and not hardcore them completely.
   Mentioned below is my conf file for the plot generation.

And the code that I am using is this:

```
perl circos-0.66/bin/circos --conf circos-tutorials-0.66/tutorials/6/6/c1.conf -outputdir . -outputfile image.png
```

CONF:

```
<<include etc/colors_fonts_patterns.conf>>
<<include ideogram.conf>>
<<include t1.conf>>
show_ticks* = no
karyotype   = karyotype/karyotype.human.txt
<image>
<<include etc/image.conf>>
</image>
chromosomes_units = 1000000
chromosomes_display_default = yes
chromosome_scale = 1
<plots>
type       = text
color      = black
label_font = bold
label_size = 24p
<plot>
file = text.Coordinates.txt
r1   = 1r
r0   = 1r
show_links     = yes
link_dims      = 0p,0p,70p,0p,10p
link_thickness = 2p
link_color     = black
</plot>
<plot>
file  = SNP_INDEL.txt
r1    = 0.9r
r0    = 0.8r
type       = text
color      = red
show_links     = yes
link_dims      = 4p,4p,8p,4p,4p
link_thickness = 2p
link_color     = red
</plot>
<plot2>
file  = Var_Class.txt
r1    = 0.7r
r0    = 0.6r
type       = text
color      = blue
show_links     = yes
link_dims      = 4p,4p,8p,4p,4p
link_thickness = 2p
link_color     = blue
</plot>
<plot>
file  = 1000G.txt
r1    = 0.5r
r0    = 0.4r
type       = text
color      = orange
show_links     = yes
link_dims      = 4p,4p,8p,4p,4p
link_thickness = 2p
link_color     = orange
</plot>
<plot>
file  = OMIM.txt
r1    = 0.3r
r0    = 0.2r
type       = text
color      = green
show_links     = yes
link_dims      = 4p,4p,8p,4p,4p
link_thickness = 2p
link_color     = green
</plot>
</plots>
```